# The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

My Java EE project was running normally in NetBeans 8.0 and Glassfish 4.0.

After rebooting my notebook, I started the server, the IDE and then tried to run the project again. I got a "The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set" message and googled to find a solution.

Many answers talk about Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant. But my NetBeans does not have an Ant tab in Miscellaneous, but in Java.

I don't know if there is any difference, I am new on this. Even adding the property "libs.CopyLibs.classpath=/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar" on Java > Ant the project don't build. By adding this many other errors appear.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if you still need this (I guess you do not), however, if someone is stuck like I once was, the answer to this is simple:

In netbeans 8.0+ (not sure if any lower versions have the same "inconvinient") when you go to

> Tools -> Options -> Miscellanous -> Ant

(or at least you try to go there) you just won´t see such tab, instead, go to

> Tools -> Options -> Java and you will see the Ant tab.

Nex, this is what you should do:

put the following property and set it with the location of the org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask jar.

It is usually located at:

> Netbeans Installation Directory\java\ant\extra\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

Your final property should be:

> libs.CopyLibs.classpath=Netbeans Installation Directory\java\ant\extra\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issues as yours and I've spent many times for finding a solution and at last, I fixed this issue.

You should fix build.properties in NetBeans or eclipse original folder.

**Example:** `C:/Users/Luiz/Appdata/RomingData/Netbeans/build.properties`.

You can see `libs.CopyDir` in your `build.properties` and then you must match the j2se library jar file path with `libs.CopyDir` path

Please check [this blog post](http://sbillah.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-get-rid-of-libscopylibsclasspath.html) for further reference.

*OR*

You may edit Ant url [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm309.png).

Thank you.